# ASP finds dropdown with 0 elements but the elements are there

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I'm using ASP to look for the selected value in a dropdown box. The dropdown box choices are generated at load time. Here is the JavaScript for that:

```
function CreateDepartmentDropdown(data) {
    var dropdown = document.getElementById("department_dropdown");
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var array = data[i].split(',');
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = array[0];
        option.innerHTML = array[1];
        dropdown.add(option);
    }
}
```

And it looks like this:

[image]

Looks fine to me. Then I checked the HTML out too just to be sure:

[image]

That looks great too. Now here is where the issue comes up. When I press submit this delegate fires in C# (still only testing while making this):

```
void Activity_Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int fye = Int32.Parse(fye_dropdown.Value);
    String activity_name = activity_name_field.Value;
    String activity_responsible = responsible_field.Value;
    int department = Int32.Parse(department_dropdown.Value);
    String activity_start = datepicker_start.Value;
    String activity_end = datepicker_end.Value;
}
```

And when I debug this it stops at department saying that it's malformed. Looking at `department_dropdown.Value` in the immediate window turns up an empty string and the dropdown itself has 0 children.

Why would this return an empty response when the list is clearly there? How would I go about fixing this?

Comment: You can't create HTML at clientside and expect that the server even cares about it. It simply doesn't exist.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Okay. Do you know how I'd get around this predicament? I'd really like not to hardcode it.

Comment: You could use a `HiddenField` and store the selected value there. Then you can read this value at serverside.

Answer (score 1):

The client-side items won't get posted back to the server like this.

The easiest way is to Serialize the array as Json, put it in a `hidden` input element's `value` :

In your markup:

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="Server" ID="department_dropdown_items" cssclass="department_dropdown_items" />

<asp:HiddenField runat="Server" ID="department_dropdown_selected" cssclass="department_dropdown_selected" />
```

Your Javascript:

```
function CreateDepartmentDropdown(data) {
    var dropdown = document.getElementById("department_dropdown");
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var array = data[i].split(',');
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = array[0];
        option.innerHTML = array[1];
        dropdown.add(option);
    }
    $(".department_dropdown_items").text(JSON.Stringify(data));
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form").submit(function(e) {
         $(".department_dropdown_selected").text( $("#department_dropdown").value);
    });
});
```

then use it in the code behind:

```
void Activity_Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] data = new JavascriptSerializer().Deserialize<string[]>(department_dropdown_items.Value);
    string selectedValue = department_dropdown_selected.Value;

    int fye = Int32.Parse(fye_dropdown.Value);
    String activity_name = activity_name_field.Value;
    String activity_responsible = responsible_field.Value;
    int department = Int32.Parse(department_dropdown.Value);
    String activity_start = datepicker_start.Value;
    String activity_end = datepicker_end.Value;
}
```

The code is not tested. Tell me if it's not working :)

Comment: I will test it first thing in the morning. Thanks friend :)

Comment: It didn't work. data ends up being null and selectedValue is an empty String.

Comment: I forgot to add `runat="server"`

Comment: And you should've referenced jQuery for this to work. I can create a jQuery-free version if you want :)

Comment: It was referenced. But it's fine, I made my own solution :) Though for future users it would probably be nice to have a jQuery free version just in case?

Comment: your solution is actually good, and more importantly its 'your' solution :) and I will add the jQuery-free code too

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up doing the following:

- Make a Hidden asp element called `department_dropdown_selected_value`
- Then in a Script tag I made the following function:

.

```
function GetDepartmentDropdownValue(sel) {
    var hidden_field = document.getElementById('department_dropdown_selected_value');
    hidden_field.value = sel.value;
}
```

- Then in my HTML I did this: `<select class="form-control" id="department_dropdown" onchange="GetDepartmentDropdownValue(this)">`
- Then I can just simply do this in C#: `int department = Int32.Parse(department_dropdown_selected_value.Value);`